# preparing sitemap of an ajax website?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, google-search-console

I coded a website which is working full of ajax.

```
 www.example.com/#page1
 www.example.com/#page2
```

these are the link examples of the website. I added sitemap Google Webmaster Tools.

```
 <url>
 <loc>http://www.example.com/#page1</loc>
 <priority>0.8</priority>
 </url>
```

sitemap.xml has all link on the website. But googlebot doesn't understand the links and didn't indexed them. I must index all pages to google. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an exclamation mark after the hash and then fix your webserver to handle these URLs

Read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)